# Why is the ArrayList size field not transient?

Tags: java, serialization, java-custom-serialization

Java's `ArrayList` uses custom serialization and explicitly writes the `size`. Nevertheless, size is not marked in `ArrayList` as `transient`. Why is size written two times: once via `defaultWriteObject` and again vis `writeInt(size)` as shown below (`writeObject` method)?

```
s.defaultWriteObject();

// Write out size as capacity for behavioral compatibility with clone()
s.writeInt(size);

// Write out all elements in the proper order.
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    s.writeObject(elementData[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR

It exists solely for compatibility with old java versions.

#### details

If you take a look at the comment above `s.writeInt(size)`, you can see that this is supposed to be the capacity. In previous java versions, the serialized form of `ArrayList` had a size and a capacity.

Both of them represent actual properties of an `ArrayList`. The `size` represents the number of items in the `ArrayList` while the `capacity` refers to the number of of possible items (length of the array) in it without the array needing to be recreated.

If you take a look at `readObject`, you can see that the capacity is ignored:

```java
// Read in capacity
s.readInt(); // ignored
```

This is because it was used in previous java versions and it still needs to be written/read to preserve compatibility.

If you look at [the matching JDK6 sources](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk6/blob/3e49aa876353eaa215cde71eb21acc9b7f9872a0/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L693), you can see that this was in fact used previously. If you have a serialized JDK6 `ArrayList` and try to deserialize it with a newer JDK, it will work. But if the capacity was just skipped, this would fail and you couldn't deserialize anything with an `ArrayList` from that old version.